# SQL SERVER Fichero de Transacciones LDF

Tags: sql, sql-server

He empezado a usar `sql-server`, en la base de datos he configurado que el fichero de transacciones vaya creciendo un 10% según vaya necesitando, pero hasta un tamaño máximo de 2Gb.

Cuándo el fichero de transacciones (ldf) llegue al limite establecido de 2Gb, ¿Se estanca o va renovando su contenido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando llega al máximo se estanca y da un Error 9002. deberías hacer un plan de mantenimiento que cuando se haga Backup de la BD y Log, borre este ultimo para dejarlo limpio.
te dejo un link de microsoft 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms175495%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Comment: Gracias Ariel Octavio. Era lo que me temia. Leeré el link que me has pasado.

Answer (score 1):

depende de como tengas configurado el recovery mode. En modo simple hay terminar el checkpoint se liberan los VLF, en modo full luego de un backup del log,full o dif. Por eso si tenes modo full es aconsejable tener una buena politica de backups

Comment: Gracias user4919.. En mi caso se ha hecho un sistema de backups